# Cannot create a table inside a Dialog Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-dialog

The Dialog Opens fine,but there is no Table tag,i also cant see any error, so that i can sort out whats wrong.

```
function CreateDialog(data){
    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        height: 300,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        open: function() {
            jQuery('dialog-form').append('<table><tr>');
            jQuery.each(data, function(key, value) {
                jQuery('dialog-form').append("<td>"+value+"</td>");
            });
            jQuery('dialog-form').append('</tr></table>')
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change:

```
jQuery('dialog-form')
```

to:

```
jQuery('#dialog-form')
```

You're missing `#` to target `id` here.

Comment: yes, but i was unable to accept it , at that time it said me to wait for 9 mins